# Java 9 - URL InputStream and save to file with OutputStream freeze application flow

Tags: java, inputstream, freeze, outputstream

I'm trying to save response from URL on file with InputStream  and OutputStream java . After the download of X bytes, the  program freeze, no error no exception , nothing .
I tryed with a lot s of solution (Outputstream buffer byte but all solutions fond give me same problem).
Maybe It can be caused by remote server that doesn't responde after a period of time. But I have no error and noexception.

This basic example freeze:

```
try (InputStream in = new URL("http://192.168.1.1:81//proc/kcore").openStream();
         OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get("output.txt"))) {

        // convert input stream to output stream
        long length = in.transferTo(out);

        System.out.println("Bytes transferred: " + length);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Program downloads about 2500 bytes than freeze.
No error and no exception.

Any idea? Thanks all!!

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: You don't see errors or exceptions because you don't set a "read timeout" to handle the case where server simply stops sending more data. Why did you pick /proc/kcore? It's not a regular file on Linux but a kernel interface to ram, I don't think reading it from start to end even makes sense

Answer (score -2):

Sorry @Progman, next time I will post correctly and thanks Joni, finally I found a solutions using Apache Commons IO - FileUtils

```
 try {
            FileUtils.copyURLToFile(
                    new URL(myUrl),
                    new File(input.getFilename()),
                    3000,
                    3000);
        }catch (SocketTimeoutException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("SocketTimeoutException" );

        }
```

Thanks

Comment: That's not the correct way to detect a specific exception, and you can't just ignore all the others. The functional difference here is not the Apache library but the timeouts.

Comment: There is no reason to use a third-party library here. It's all in the standard API already. `URLConnection c = new URL(myUrl).openConnection(); c.setConnectTimeout(3000); c.setReadTimeout(3000); try(InputStream is=c.getInputStream()) { Files.copy(is, Paths.get("output.txt")); }`